# Django reverse foreign key constraint

Tags: django, foreign-keys, constraints

I have 2 models, Asset and Trade. The Trade model has Asset linked by a foreign key, which allows null values depending on the status of the Trade. An Asset always needs to be linked to a Trade by the foreign key. An Asset can have many Trades, but a Trade can only have 1 Asset. The problem is that sometimes an Asset is created without a Trade, and this needs to fail because it then causes further errors as it shouldn't be possible. How can I ensure the reverse foreign key is never null for the Asset model, but keep the on_delete parameter as SET_NULL?

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    asset = models.ForeignKey(
        Asset,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
)
    
class Asset(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: This is validation that you should be adding into your views.

Comment: Also, this makes little sense - why can an `Asset` not exist without a `Trade`? I think the issue here is not your validation so much as the way you are thinking about your DB structure.

Comment: It seems, logic is little incorrect. keeping on_delete paramter as SET_NULL is not related with your logic(Asset should have Trade).

We need to validate in View, when asset is created and when trade is deleted.
set_null is applied when asset is deleted (It is not related to current behaviour).

Comment: An `Asset` can't exist without a `Trade` because a `Trade` is required to create it. This `Trade` will have an "open" status. A `Trade` with a "closed" status won't have an `Asset`. Although it can be created by a view, it can also be created by an automated process. The solution may be that the code in this process needs to be changed, but my first choice is to fix it using the model.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Many to one instead of foraing key

Comment: OP already has a many-to-one relationship by definition.

Comment: I understand, but models.ForaingKey establishes a one-to-one relationship, instead you need to use many-to-one.

Comment: `models.ForeignKey` establishes a many-to-one relationship. One-to-one relationships are achieved with `models.OneToOneField`

Comment: Exactly. FK is a many-to-one. @UtkuMutlu - swap the files around in the way you're thinking and you'll see - in this case, one asset can be on many trades. 

If one asset is limited to a single trade, that is different and should use a one to one field. True 1-2-1 fields are often redundant though, and could just be a field on the main model instead. Not always, but often :)

Comment: Opss, I was wrong. Thanks for the fix :)